# svg not found en nuxt local

Tags: vue.js, svg, nuxt

Quiero mostrar unas banderas de paises y para ello encontré un plugin (https://www.growthbunker.dev/vueflags/)

Las imágenes de las banderas son svg y estan ubicadas en:

```
.app/
  ../assets/flags <- ACA
  ../components
  ../layouts
  .. etc
```

La configuración del plugin:

```
// plugins/vueflags.js

import Vue from "vue";
import VueFlags from "@growthbunker/vueflags";

Vue.use(VueFlags, {
    // Specify the path of the folder where the flags are stored.
    iconPath: 'assets/flags',
  });
```

Y finalmente lo llamo dentro del componente (deberia aparecer la bandera de francia)

```
 <gb-flag code="fr" size="small" />
```

Cuando levanto el proyecto recibo el siguiente error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/flags/fr.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

Alguna recomendación? Muchas gracias

> Intenté poniendo  `iconPath: '~/assets/flags',` y el error es prácticamente el mismo:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/~/assets/flags/fr.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

---

También tengo esto en `nuxt.config.js`

```
buildModules: [
    [
      "@nuxtjs/vuetify",
      {
        /* module options */
      },
    ],
    ["@nuxtjs/svg"],
  ],
```

Comment: (la solucion era usar la carpeta "static") - me la respondieron en SO en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216748/404-not-found-svg-in-nuxt/70224537#70224537